# Changing a class variables type

Tags: java

I have two different interfaces which employ the same methods but dont implement or extend each other. These two interfaces are each extended by another class which implements the interfaces methods

I then have a class which is located in a seperate package which calls the interface methods.

So the class has methods which calls the methods of the interfaces, which are all the same.

```
public void doThis(){
    connection.doThis(); 
}

public void doThat(){
    connection.doThat();
}

public void doAnother(){
    connection.doAnother();
}
```

Now, i want to make the variable **connection** work for both interface1 and interface2.

My idea was to set connection as a class variable

```
Object connection
```

and then to change it type to interface1 or interface2 depending on a condition:

```
if(this){ 
//condition which converts connection to type interface1
}
else{ 
//condition which converts connection to type interface2
}
```

How do i do this. Can i do this?

I have been given an interface which can not be changed, yet does not implement remote. But my project uses RMI. So i created a 2nd interface in a seperate package which implemets Remote. Thus the reason for 2 different interfaces that do he same thing.

Comment: Why not use generics?

Comment: If both interfaces have exact same methods then you don't need to do anything, hold reference type as either `Interface1` or `Inteface2`.

Comment: Why are there two identical interfaces each with one implementing class? It is very likely that you just want one interface with two implementations, in which case you can have your member variable be of the type of that one interface.

Comment: One interface extends remote, the other dosent. This cant be changed

Comment: Have you tried giving a common interface to both classes? Even if you can't modify one class X, perhaps you can extend X and make the new class also implement the interface of the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to make the class containing the method 'connection' public, as it would be accessible from all packages.

Comment: Thats not really an answer

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a really weird setup, but I won't question you.

If you know the condition at the method call site (eg, the condition is a constant flag passed to the method), you could parameterize the method with a generic instead. For example:

```
public class TestGenerics {
    public static interface A {
        public void a();
    }

    public static interface B {
        public void a();
    }

    public static class C implements A, B {
        public void a() {
            System.out.println("a");
        }
    }

    public static <T> T getCAsT() {
        return (T) new C();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = TestGenerics.<A>getCAsT();
        B b = TestGenerics.<B>getCAsT();
        a.a();
        b.a();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I would try to merge the two interfaces in some way.

Comment: **public static class C implements A**. and **public static class D implements B**. Does that change your answer

Comment: If different classes are implementing different interfaces, I don't see what you want to do. Is `connection` an instance of `C` or `D`?

Comment: i want connection to be an instance of interface 1 if(this)...else i want connection to be an instance of interface2